# Acceder al atributo de un componente concreto dentro de una lista en Java

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Hola buen día es la primera vez que hago una solicitud de ayuda pero ya estoy bastante desesperado,
estoy haciendo un programa para restaurante en el cual tengo un panel con un botón que genera JLabels y estos tienen un mouseevent que muestra en otro panel información guardada en una base de datos, del JLabel solo necesito acceder a su texto pero el problema esta en que con el primer label que genera mi boton si realiza lo esperado pero si genero un segundo o mas label's todos muestran lo mismo que lo del ultimo label generado, lo que me dice que al dar clic en cualquier label me esta regresando el texto del ultimo label.

Aquí mando las partes de mi código involucradas en el problema.

Esto esta en mi Main.

```
    public static List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();;
    public static int NTkt = 0;
    public static JTable tblOrden;
    public static JPanel pnlTickets;
    public static JPanel pnlComanda ;
    public static JLabel label;
JButton btnTicket = new JButton("+");
        btnTicket.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                CtrlTicket.nuevo();                         
                }});
        pnlComanda.updateUI();
        pnlTickets.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        btnTicket.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnTicket.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.BOLD, 80));
        btnTicket.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnTicket.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnTicket.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED, null, null));
        btnTicket.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        pnlTickets.add(btnTicket);
```

Y estos se encuentra en una clase fuera

```
public static DefaultTableModel comanda(DefaultTableModel modelo, int ntkt, JLabel label) {//Main L:400
        int tkt = 0;
        modelo.setRowCount(0);
        modelo.setColumnCount(0);
        Main.pnlComanda.updateUI();
        Main.labels = new ArrayList<>();        
        tkt= Integer.valueOf(label.getText());
//segun yo aqui arriba esta el problema, debe ser el label que toma para traer el texto.
        Main.pnlComanda.setName(String.valueOf(tkt));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Main.pnlComanda.getName());
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection con = Conexion.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT Producto, Cantidad, Precio FROM orden WHERE Ticket = ?";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(Main.pnlComanda.getName()));
            rs = ps.executeQuery();         
            modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");
            modelo.addColumn("Producto");
            modelo.addColumn("Precio");
            Main.tblOrden.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(70);
            Main.tblOrden.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(170);
            Main.tblOrden.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(60);
            while (rs.next()) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object [] {rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(1),rs.getDouble(3)});
            }
            Main.pnlComanda.updateUI();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
        }       
        return modelo;      
    }

    public static void nuevo() {
        
        ModTicket Tkt = new ModTicket();
        CtrlTicket CrearTkt = new CtrlTicket();
        CrearTkt.crear(Tkt);
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = Conexion.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT MAX(ticket) as id FROM ticket";
        try {           
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();                 
            while(rs.next()) {
                Main.NTkt= rs.getInt("id");                     
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Main.label= new JLabel(String.valueOf(Main.NTkt));
        Main.pnlTickets.add(Main.label);
        Main.labels.add(Main.label);
        Main.label.setName(String.valueOf(Main.NTkt));
        Main.label.setVerticalTextPosition(3);
        Main.label.setVerticalAlignment(0);
        Main.label.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        Main.label.setHorizontalTextPosition(0);
        Main.label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        Main.label.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        Main.label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                CtrlTicket.comanda(Main.modelo, Main.NTkt, Main.label);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Y aqui una imagen de la pantalla

[image: Muestra]

De antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo y una disculpa si no formule bien este escrito es que es mi primera vez.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion, mi error estaba en el;

`public static JLabel label`

Dentro de Main, es que en otra parte que no tenia que ver con el problema ocupaba hacer uso de uno y no me di cuenta que por usar el mismo en ambos interfería con el método que estaba usando para generar componentes, una disculpa por si los hice malgastar su tiempo de igual manera si gustan dar opiniones de mi código estas son bien recibidas, gracias de nuevo por su atención y una vez mas una disculpa por los inconvenientes.

La solución fue pasar mi método nuevo dentro del evento del botón y corregir el constructor, al final el botón quedo así:

```
JButton btnTicket = new JButton("+");
        btnTicket.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                ModTicket Tkt = new ModTicket();
                CtrlTicket CrearTkt = new CtrlTicket();
                CrearTkt.crear(Tkt);
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                Connection con = Conexion.getConnection();
                String sql = "SELECT MAX(ticket) as id FROM ticket";
                try {           
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();                 
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        Main.NTkt= rs.getInt("id");                     
                    }
                    con.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                JLabel label= new JLabel(String.valueOf(NTkt));
                pnlTickets.add(label);
                labels.add(label);
                label.setName(String.valueOf(NTkt));
                label.setVerticalTextPosition(3);
                label.setVerticalAlignment(0);
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
                label.setHorizontalTextPosition(0);
                label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                label.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                
                label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        CtrlTicket.comanda(modelo, NTkt, label);
                    }
                }); 
                }});
        pnlComanda.updateUI();
        pnlTickets.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        btnTicket.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnTicket.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.BOLD, 80));
        btnTicket.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnTicket.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnTicket.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED, null, null));
        btnTicket.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        pnlTickets.add(btnTicket);
```